# database locking

Tags: c#, locking, deadlock

I am wondering how is a (simpler) way to implement locking in a database driven application (in c# for example, and I refer to either desktop applications or web applications all connecting to a WCF/web service handling the database operations).

I understand from this wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science) that I can do optimistic locking which is to check if update were made since last read and throw an error accordingly and ask the user to reread the data and try to update it again. But if there are a bigger number of users doing updates at the same time, the downside is that there can be many update trial and errors.

As a conclusion I think optimistic locking is an option.
Is there other options that are not complicated to implement?
I think that locking and mutexes are an option but I cannot think of a way to implement the "if" condition to see WHICH record is blocked, such that it does not lead to deadlocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy way to lock data can be to create a simple table on your database with columns like:

column 1: Table Name
column 2: row id
column 3: locked (boolean)
 after all your software can read this table to know which record is in modification.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding deadlocks is about acquiring locks in the right order. For example, before modifying the data of some particular user you could UPDLOCK that user so that no concurrent transactions can modify the user at the same time.

This was just an example. You need to find a scheme that is very likely to acquire locks in a consistent order.

For reads, you can use snapshot isolation.

Anyway, many applications only have deadlocks in particular spots. Maybe you could just ignore the issue and fix any spurious deadlocks in production by just changing a small bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what database product(s) you use or are considering.  In PostgreSQL (if that is an option for you), there is a technique which is similar to Optimistic Concurrency Control (OCC) but with fewer rollbacks which is used for `SERIALIZABLE` transactions.  It is called Serializable Snapshot Isolation (SSI).  Basically, OCC cancels a transaction on the basis of a single read-write anti-dependency, while SSI only cancels a transaction if there is a pattern of multiple read-write anti-dependencies which research has shown will always be present if non-serializable effects are possible.

It is a new technique, first published in an academic paper in 2008 and first present in a public production database in PostgreSQL 9.1, released in 2011.

Obviously there are a lot of other ways to approach the issue, but your interest in OCC seemed to suggest this might be appealing for you.  Every technique which preserves integrity in the face of concurrent transactions will involve blocking, transaction rollback, or both.  "Traditional" Strict Two Phase Locking (S2PL) techniques lean more toward blocking, while OCC and SSI have minimal blocking (and thus more concurrency) but can have significantly more rollbacks in some workloads.  The best technique to use is definitely workload dependent.

You can read more about SSI in [the PostgreSQL documentation for the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE), [a Wiki page with some examples](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI), [the initial paper from ACM SIGMOD 2008](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1620587), [the doctoral thesis of Michael J. Cahill](http://hdl.handle.net/2123/5353), or the paper by Dan R. K. Ports and myself which has been accepted for presentation at VLDB 2012 and should be published by VLDB soon.